# Apps for screen rotation hotkey?

Tags: display, macos, screen

So I'm using the latest El Capitan, and I find myself using my **'external'** monitor both portrait and landscape mode simultaneously.
It's been quite bugging to go into system prefs. and changing the screen orientation every time I rotate my screen.

Is there a way to simply rotate the orientation without having the hassle to go through all those steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.magesw.com/displayrotation/

This program is added on to menubar, and basically allows user to change to rotation accordingly.

This also allows you to press cmd + ctrl + opt + 0 to return to landscape